# How to stop HTML list going down when browser size adjusts?

Tags: html, css

Alright, so I created a header on my website and a header which contains a list to help user navigate.

Here is what my header looks like:
[image]

Now, lets say I make my chrome browser window smaller.

Naturally, HTML tries to make it fit in and it displays like this:
[image]

You could see how the Vote link moved down.

How can I stop this behavior? If the browser window is shrunk, the Vote item should not go down, it just will not display until the browser is big enough again. How can I do this in CSS?

Current code:

```
/*Header Text*/
#header h1 {
    font-family: "smooth";
    font-size: 45px;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    height: 0;
}

/* Make unordered list horizontle */
#header ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-top: -12.5px;
    margin-left: 270px;
}

/* Make unordered list horizontle */
#header ul li {
    display: inline;
}

/* Make boxed & colored */
#header ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: .2% 3%;
    color: #FFF; /*Text color, when not hovered*/
}

/* Make change colors, when hovered on */
#header ul li a:hover{
    color: lightgray; /*Text color*/
}

/* Header box */
#header{
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #3385ff;
    margin-top: -9px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

/*Remove line*/
#header a{
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* Header navigation font */
#header li{
    font-family: "smooth";
}
```

And for HTML:

```
<div id="header">
<a href="index.html"><h1>FlareHub</h1></a>
<ul>
  <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>News</a></li>
  <li><a href="vipinfo.html"><i class="fa fa-star"></i>VIP</a></li>
  <li><a href="games.html"><i class="fa fa-trophy"></i>Games</a></li>
  <li><a href="vote.html"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i>Vote</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i>Account</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="login.php"><i class="fa fa-key"></i>Login</a>
    <a href="signup.php"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>Signup</a>
    <a href="help.html"><i class="fa fa-life-ring"></i>Help & Support</a>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should look into [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to hide menu items as the width is changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean for it to be able to go off of the page, you can go the route of:

```
#header ul {
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: none; }
```

If you want it to be able to scroll, leave off the `overflow: none`.

Note: Media queries can be tricky due to high-res phones and low-res monitors, but they are worth looking into.